# Getting strings between certain string and a special character

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get data between string and special character.

How can I do this in JS?

Below is my code:

```js
    var string = '(CATCH: dummy)';
    var TitleRegex = /\((CATCH:.*?)\)/;
    var titleData = string.match(TitleRegex);
```

Output should be : dummy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could possibly fix the current expression by moving the opening `(` to the location right after `:`, [`/\(CATCH:(.*?)\)/`](https://regex101.com/r/X7mX9x/1), and then grabbing Group 1 value using something like `var titleData = string.match(TitleRegex)[1]`.

I'd suggest a bit more precise pattern here:

```js
var string = '(CATCH: dummy)';
var TitleRegex = /\(CATCH:\s*([^()]*)\)/;
var titleData = string.match(TitleRegex);
if (titleData) {
  console.log(titleData[1]);
}
```

The regex is `\(CATCH:\s*([^()]*)\)`:

- `\(CATCH:`  - a `(CATCH:` substring
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `([^()]*)` - Capturing group 1: any 0 or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a `)` char.

You may actually use `/\(CATCH:([^()]*)\)/`  (without `\s*`) and just use `titleData[1].trim()` to get rid of any eventual whitespace on both ends of the required value.